# SendGrid webhook signature verification

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am trying to setup SendGrid webhook using Signature verification. I am using NodeJs and cannot use the SendGrid Node libraries, so need to work out how to do without those.

Here is the code I currently have. I also notice SendGrid doesn't have a test API for signature verification, is there any other way to test other than sending emails?

```
app.post('/sendgrid/delivery', function (req, res) {

    var signature = req.headers['X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature'];
    var timestamp = req.headers['X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp'];
    var payload = req.rawBody;
    var payload2 = req.body;

    if (!signature || !timestamp) return res.sendStatus(500);

    var publicKey = 'MFkwEw...Q==';

    // Decode here....

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```